# HAProxy hides real IP on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, haproxy

I am running a WordPress site on IIS with a HAProxy running on Ubuntu 12.04 in front.

Problem is that the HAProxy hides the real IP for WordPress
This makes the WordPress only see like `10.12.3.50` from all users.

Is there anyone who has a fix for this.  A plugin for WordPress, or a patch for the HAProxy?

Comment: The real IP is usually somewhere in `$_SERVER`, what do you need it for? Can you change the code that needs it to look for a different field?

Comment: I like the real IP if some goes wrong. Now I have to look in several logs to find out where the problem is coming from. There are also function see if some have multiple account from same IP.  Now all has the same IP so this can not be turned on.

Comment: It might be worth Googling `haproxy real ip` it shows some interesting results, like this: [Remote IP's with HAProxy](http://serverfault.com/q/30311) (the answer mentioning TProxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `forwardfor` option to get the original requestor's IP address in a `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP Request header.

I'm not sure if WP can be configured to log this header but for sure, it's in HAProxy's logs. It's very useful when troubleshooting.

**Sources:**

1. https://serverfault.com/a/30336/101643
2. personal experience

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the Input.
I will just explain some how I got it to work:

HAProxy change.  Here I added these option to every redirect.

```
nano haproxy.cfg
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor
```

For the IIS I visited this page: 
http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/03/03/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr.aspx 
Here I downloaded `arr_helper_x86.zip` (There is also an x64 bits version)
Then I just installed this on my IIS server, and viola I now see correct IP

Thanks to Ianthe for helping me out in correct direction.